# SoapUI script assertion gotoStepByName

Tags: groovy, soapui, assertions

Background: I am using SoapUI 5.0.0 (not pro) and I have a testStep SCRIPT ASSERTION that I use to check the response that the testStep receives. 
If a certain condition is met, i wish to start another testStep (can run once the script is over).

My problem is: `testRunner` does not work in script assertion so I cannot use `testRunner.gotoStepByName("step5")`

My question: is there a different option I can call that does work in a script assertion that will make the test jump to that certain testStep ?

Answer (score 0):

In `script assetion` you've available `context` variable, this variable is an instance of [`com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/testcase/WsdlTestRunContext.html).

Through this class you can get [`com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestCaseRunner`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/testcase/WsdlTestRunContext.html) using `getTestRunner()` method and from here use `gotoStepByName(String name)`.

You can use the follow code in your assertion script when your conditions are met:

```
context.getTestRunner().gotoStepByName('step5')
```

**Note that running the `script assertion` "alone" the `context.getTestRunner()` returns `null` because you're running it in `assertion` context, the same applies if you run it from the `TestStep`. To get the `runner` property correctly you've to run the `TestStep` which contains the `script assertion` from the `TestCase`.**

Hope this helps,